# Regexp in Vim Not working as expected

Tags: regex, vim

Why is the following regex

```
/\d{2, 4}/
```

which I expect to identify all between 2 and 4 digits in a text not working when I run it on the following text

```
1234567890
```

in vim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your expression: 1. the first brace needs to be escaped, 2. there should be no space inside the quantifier.

```
/\d\{2,4}/
```

See `:help /\{`.

If you turn on `very magic`, e.g. by starting the expression with `\v`, you don't need to escape the first brace:

```
/\v\d{2,4}/
```